# Как оптимизировать парсинг?

Tags: оптимизация, парсер

Друзья есть код:

```
$start = microtime(true);
$cookies=tmpfile();
$ch = curl_init("https://gskip.taobao.com/json/processUserCookie.htm?site=CN_zh-cn_CNY&from=1&callback=jsonp687&t=1457852034423");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'IE20');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookies);//используем куки
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookies);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_exec($ch);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,'https://s.taobao.com/search?data-key=cat&data-value=9&data-action=add&ajax=true&_ksTS=1457852489793_588&callback=jsonp589&q=&imgfile=&commend=all&ssid=s5-e&search_type=item&sourceId=tb.index&spm=a21bo.7724922.8452-taobao-item.2&ie=utf8&initiative_id=tbindexz_20160313&tfsid=TB1KlPpLVXXXXb6aXXXXXXXXXXX&app=imgsearch');
$page=curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
//$json = substr($page,5,-1);
print_r($page);
$time = microtime(true) - $start;
printf('<br />Скрипт выполнялся %.4F сек.', $time);
```

возможно ли как нибудь оптимизировать что бы быстро обработать? а то время выполнения до 10-30 сек. иногда бывает

Comment: парсинга здесь нет, вы просто загружаете какую-то страницу (просто текст, даже не обрабатываете его), поэтому можно либо поставить таймаут на меньшее время (тогда некоторые страницы не будут загружены), либо запускать несколько таких процессов. Кроме того, возможно, у вас просто медленный интернет, а значит хоть что делай - ничего не поможет

Comment: @BOPOH, Да, заметил что при меленном интернете работает медленно даже очень, а с быстрым быстро до 7.сек. но думал что можно по средству php или js можно как то ускорит))

Answer (score 4):

Из кода следует, что тут проблема не сколько с парсингом, сколько с загрузкой http-файла. Насколько я понял, файлы прекрасно отдаются не только по HTTPS, но и по HTTP. Попробуйте заменить https на http - будет быстрее. Если у вас потом какие-то мощные вычисления и потребления памяти в скрипте, чтобы не держать ресурсы, можно попробовать загружать данные заранее по крону, а потом другим скриптом уже разбирать по мере подгрузки данных. Однако, если вам сторонний сервер отдает страницу с лагами и задержкой, то уже трудно сделать что-то кардинальное для ускорения. Пересмотрите архитектуру, например, загружайте страницу по планировщику.

Comment: По http не получилось (301 Moved Permanently) только https просить, насколько я знаю крон тоже не получится ведь параметры запроса бывает разные.

Comment: 301 - это перенаправление, посмотрите куда перенаправляет? На https?

Comment: Да на https скидывает

Comment: Вы выше написали, что у вас большая зависимость от скорости интернета. Если вы внесете проект на сервер на хороший канал, скорость будет довольно высокой. Или это локальный проект и парсинг будет всегда на локальной машине?

Comment: Да нет, это на сервер такие результаты вот: [ссылка](http://tajmarket.ru/tetes/files/www/imagesearch.php) пример выдача нужный текст, но запрос такой же

Comment: Да, у меня 51 секунда - это много. Переводите парсинг на крон-задания, извлекайте информацию в фоне и предоставляйте поиск уже по вашей локальной базе данных, быстро. Или двигайте свой сервер поближе к источнику (я так понимаю это Китай?), возможно будет побыстрее.

Comment: вот сейчас у меня вышло на "Скрипт выполнялся 3.4662 сек." да это Китай, я не очень много работал с крон ом и не совсем понимаю как тут поможет крон? ведь крон выполняет действия по времени.

Comment: Смотрите, вы не можете отдавать пользователю страницу минуту - никто не будет ждать. Плюс если от вас будет много соединений, да еще и медленных - вас вычислит администратор и будет блокировать (почему медленные запросы - это плохо, лучше отдельным вопросом, если интересно). Поэтому обычно в такой ситуации парсят данные в фоне, запуская задания через определенный интервал, например, кроном - есть ему что делать - он пасит, нет - завершает работу. Он перетаскивает вам всю нужную информацию в локальную базу данных и по ней вы ищите и отдаете пользователю ответ очень быстро.

Comment: это хорошо если бы параметры у запроса были бы понятным, но какие параметры будет у запроса решит пользователь  и в зависимости от параметра идет выдача например: `$data = array(
    'ajax'=>'true',
                         'data-value'=> $tabsp,
                         'pictproperty'=>$tabsp,
                         'app'=>'imgsearch',
                         'callback'=>'json',
                         'cat'=>$catsp,
                         'tfsid'=>$id,
     );` а вот запрос: ` curl_init('https://s.taobao.com/search?'.http_build_query($data));` по этому крон тут не может помочь.